# How to find missing numbers in access file

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to find missing numbers in access

```
District(RDS)-------Divisional Secretariat(RD)------------REGNO
1-------------------1--------------------------------------10
1-------------------1--------------------------------------11
1-------------------1--------------------------------------14
1-------------------2---------------------------------------1
1-------------------2---------------------------------------2
1-------------------2---------------------------------------4
2-------------------1--------------------------------------38
2-------------------1--------------------------------------39
2-------------------2-------------------------------------112
2-------------------2-------------------------------------113
2-------------------2-------------------------------------116
```

According to above example;
1->1---> ***12 &1 3*** are missing
1->2---> ***3*** is missing
2->1---> ***37*** is missing
2->2---> ***114 & 115*** are missing

I've attempted an approach that takes the above table and starts like

```
SELECT DISTINCT RDS,RD,([REGNO]+1) AS MissingFrom,
DMin("REGNO","DTH","REGNO>" & [REGNO]) AS MissingUntil
FROM DTH
WHERE (((DMin("REGNO","DTH","REGNO>" & [REGNO]))<>([REGNO]+1)));
```

The entire approach use the existing numbers to find the missing "next/previous number. I'm able to output which numbers(REGNO) are missing. However I do not know ***how to group*** it with the associated **RDS** and **RD**.

I also feel like I've complicated the task, I'm looking for guidance from anyone who can help on the best / most efficient way of going about this

THANK YOU

Comment: Google is your friend. Here's one of the top results (took about 5 seconds): [Access Database. How to find missing numbers in a sequence of numbers.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-database-how-to-find-missing-numbers-in-a/63cbc353-69c1-4838-be2e-024495f5754f)

Comment: And I even wrote an article on this way back: [Find and Generate Missing Values in an Access Table](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345)

Comment: Yes.I was able to output which numbers(REGNO) are missing in a sequence. However I do not know **how to group it with the associated RDS and RD**.

Comment: How many possible combinations of RDS and RD? is there a table that defines the RegNo range for each?